# Error while building application using Ext JS

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am getting the following error while running Sencha application build production.

[image]

Login.js

> `xtype: 'login',
>       extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
>       requires: [
>       'Ext.window.Window',
>           'MyApp.view.login.LoginController',
>           'Ext.form.Panel'
>       ],`

Application.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
requires: [
'Ext.window.Window'

],
name: 'MyApp',
```

App.js

```
Ext.application({
name: 'MyApp',

extend: 'MyApp.Application',

requires: [
    'MyApp.view.login.Login',
    'Ext.window.Window'
],
```

Answer (score 1):

From the "Android" tag I deduce that you are trying to make an ExtJS 6.0.x "modern" app - which is good, because "modern" is far better for touch displays than "classic".

But "modern" toolkit does not have a Ext.window.Window. For a list of available views, please compare the [official documentation for modern toolkit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-modern/).

Depending on what you want to do, you may opt for a list, a dataview, a form, a sheet. The best overview by far over the available components gives the [Sencha Touch kitchen sink](https://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.1/examples/kitchensink/index.html). I have not found anything similar for its successor, the ExtJS "modern" toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reading better you error logs alexander say truth, using modern you can't use Ext.window.Window!

Have a look to docs, that component doesn't exist on extjs 6 modern

Comment: if you extend the class in your login you must do it in your application class not in the login

Comment: i have edited the question and added code snippets of Application.js and App.js. Please guide me where I am going wrong.